# JSONs with (supposedly) same format treated differently by BigQuery - one accepted, one rejected

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I am trying to upload JSON files to BigQuery. The JSON files are outputs from the Lighthouse auditing tool. I have made some changes them in Python to make field names acceptable for BigQuery and converted the format into newline JSON.

I am now testing this process and I have found that while for many web pages the upload runs without issue, BigQuery is rejecting some of the JSON files. The rejected JSONs always seem to be from the same website, for example, many of the audit JSONs from Topshop have failed on upload (the manipulations in Python run without issue). What I am confused by is that I can see no difference in the formatting/structure of the JSONs which succeed and fail.

I have included some examples here of the JSON files: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1x66PoDeQGfOCTEj4l3VqMIjjhdrjqs9w

The error I get from BigQuery when a JSON fails to load is this:

```
Error while reading table: build_test_2f38f439_7e9a_4206_ada6_ac393e55b8ec4_source, error message: Failed to parse JSON: No active field found.; ParsedString returned false; Could not parse value; Could not parse value; Could not parse value; Could not parse value; Could not parse value; Could not parse value; Parser terminated before end of string
```

I have also attempted to upload the failed JSONs to a new table through the interface using the autodetect feature (in an attempt to discover whether the Schema was at fault) and these uploads fail too, with the same error.

This makes me think the JSON files must be wrong, but I have copied them into several different JSON validators which all accept them as one row of valid JSON.

Any help understanding this issue would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can you load the original files without error?

Comment: Do you mean the original Lighthouse report JSONs? No, they are not formatted in newline JSON, and many of the field names include hyphens or start with numbers - which BigQuery does not allow

Answer (score 1):

When you load JSON files to BigQuery, it's good to remember that there are some limitations associated to this format. You can find them [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#limitations). Even though your files might be valid JSON files, some of them may not comply with BigQuery limitations, so I would recommend you to double check if they are actually correct for BigQuery.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the error here through a long trial and error process where I uploaded first the first-half and then the second-half of the JSON file to BigQuery. The second-half failed so I split that in half again to see which half the error occurred in. This continued until I found the line.

At a deep level of nesting there was a situation where one field was always a list of strings, but when there were no values associated with the field it appeared as an empty string (rather than an empty list). This inconsistency was causing the error. The trial and error process was long but given the vague error message and that the JSON was thousands of lines long, this seemed like the most efficient way to get there.